# Ask the user for the length of the list (n). Generate a linear list of n integers. Insert a zero after each even value. Print the new list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am supposed to ask the user to input a number then print all the numbers preceding that but, I have to insert a 0 after every even number.
I am a beginner in Python so, I don't know much.

```
n=0
length_even=[]
length_odd=[]

def length_list(n):
    length=int(input('Enter the length of the list: '))
    for i in range(1,length+1):
        if(i%2 != 0):
            length_odd.append(i)
        elif(i%2 == 0) :
            length_even.append(i)
            length_even.insert(i,0) 

    total=length_odd+length_even
    return total

length_list(n)
```

If a user enters 5, I expect the output to be [1,2,0,3,4,0,5] but, the actual output is (1,3,5,2,0,4,0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create two independent lists (length_even and length_odd) and concatenate (`+` operator) them after you have added the values to each list (length_odd contains: `1,3,5` and length_even contains: `2,0,4,0`). The result you get is therefore: `1,3,5,2,0,4,0`. Why don't you just use one list? Have a look at the code below (I made only slight changes to avoid confusion):

```py
 n=0
 lengthList = []

 def length_list(n):
     length=int(input('Enter the length of the list: '))
     for i in range(1,length+1):
         if(i%2 != 0):
             lengthList.append(i)
         elif(i%2 == 0) :
             lengthList.append(i)
             lengthList.append(0) 

     return lengthList

length_list(n)
```